# How to prove that $\frac{a}{m} > x$ given $\frac{a}{m}< \sqrt{a} < m < \frac{a}{x}$ and $x < \sqrt{a} < m < \frac{a}{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

can I ask a tip on how to prove that $\frac{a}{m} > x$, given the following relation:

$$\begin{cases}\frac{a}{m}< \sqrt{a} < m < \frac{a}{x}\\
x < \sqrt{a} < m < \frac{a}{x}
\end{cases}$$

?

I just got stuck. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: From the last inequality of third line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $m > \sqrt{a} \ge 0$, $m$ is positive.
Also $\sqrt{a}$ can only be defined if $a$ is positive, and $\frac{a}{x} > m$ means $\frac{a}{x}$ is positive, so $x$ is positive.

Now $m < \frac{a}{x}$ implies $x < \frac{a}{m}$ by multiplying both sides by the positive quantity $\frac{x}{m}$.